# VS CODE remote-ssh `code` command not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I connect to the remote server with vs code command invoked by CTRL+SHIFT+P *Remote-SSH: Connect to Host...*. Everything works fine. After some time when I try to open a new file from the vs-code terminal with the `code` command, I will get this error message:

```
/some/path/on/remote$ code some_existing_file.py                                                                                         
Unable to connect to VS Code server: Error in request.
Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1006/vscode-ipc-789269cc-6026-4d15-8ca6-<i_changed_this>.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/run/user/1001/vscode-ipc-789269cc-6026-4d15-8ca6-<i_changed_this>.sock'
}
```

Killing all running vs-code processes manually "solves" the problem. The occurence of this  problem seems to be random. Sometimes it happens 3 times within an hour, sometimes just once per day.

vs-code version: *1.66.0*

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: why use the terminal to open a file

Comment: @rioV8 Too lazy to click. I hate using the file explorer GUI in general when I can use terminal as unified interface. Especially when you are browsing nested folders, TAB autocomplete is helpful.

Comment: you can use `Ctrl+P` and type part of the filename, or `Ctrl+O`, or `Ctrl+Shift+E` and type part of the filename, you have to enable `workbench.list.keyboardNavigation`

Answer (score 3):

I was having similar issue and error message when running `code .`

The solution worked for me was to remove everything under the *HOME*'s `.vscode-server` directory

> rm -rf ~/.vscode-server

Now do the `code xxx` command again should re-install the `VS Code Server` under the `.vscode-server` folder.

Comment: I did this, and it removed all of the extensions/settings I had configured for the remote connection. The "code" command worked immediately afterwards, but it doesn't work today (I deleted the .vscode-server yesterday). I would prefer not having to reinstall my extensions each time; do you have any advice for that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this hack in your .bashrc or any other bash setup script you are using:

```
if [[ ! -z VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI ]]; then
    REMOTE_CODE_BIN_PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep "/Users/steelphase/.vscode-server/bin/.*/bin")
    if [[ -d $REMOTE_CODE_BIN_PATH ]]; then
        NEW_PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e "s~:$REMOTE_CODE_BIN_PATH~~g")
        export PATH="$REMOTE_CODE_BIN_PATH:$NEW_PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).